# Find out which font, exactly, Inkscape is using for "Monospace"?

Tags: fonts, inkscape

I made a diagram in Inkscape including some text with font "Monospace". I suspect that the name "Monospace" stands for a more specific font that may depend on my particular system configuration.

I would like to change the font family to a more specific name so that I can be sure of reproducible results on other systems. Is there a way to determine what font family exactly is "Monospace"?

Comment: [Monospace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) is a font-family rather than a specific font. It would encompass all mono spaced fonts, which have the same size for each glyph.

Comment: @Seth Thank you, I have clarified the title.

Answer (score 2):

Inkscape substitutes a system font for the `monospace` font when rendering a document for printing and other formats, so you can use that to find the underlying font:

- Create a document with sample text using the `monospace` font. You
  can also add the other default fonts, `serif` and `sans-serif`.
- Save the document as a PDF (File -> Save a Copy...).
- Open the PDF in Adobe Reader.
- In Reader, go to File -> Properties...
- In the Fonts tab, you'll find a list of fonts used in the document.

On my current system (macOS 10.15, Inkscape 1.0.2), monospace is replaced with `Andale Mono`; serif and sans-serif are replaced with `Times New Roman` and `Verdana`.

These values changed with the release of Inkscape 1.0. On my prior system (macOS 10.13, XQuartz 2.7.11, Inkscape 0.92), the defaults were `Bitstream Vera Sans Mono`, `Bitstream Vera Serif`, and `Bitstream Vera Sans`. These fonts were installed with XQuartz.

[This post](http://www.inkscapeforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=20650#p89329) reports that on Windows, Inkscape uses `Courier New` for monospace, and `Times New Roman` and `Verdana` for the other defaults. As noted in the comments, at least some Windows systems are using `DejaVuSansMono` for monospace.

If you don't have Adobe Reader installed, you can simply use a text editor to find the fonts in the PDF. Search for `/FontFamily`.

Comment: Interestingly, on my Windows system, monospace has been resolved to `DejaVuSansMono`.

Comment: @JojOatXGME - Thanks for the note. It looks like a lot of things changed with Inkscape 1.0 - I updated the answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Searching for `/FontFamily` gives gibberish names like `FEFF00D7CF53545D`. Running `mutool info qq.pdf` gives similar gibberish names but with some crazy Unicode characters.